# The block after 'let' is unfinished - try/with

Tags: f#

Follow Code F#:

```
try
    let result = 100/0
with
    | :? Exception as ex -> printfn ex.Message
```

I get an error:

> The block after 'let' is unfinished. Each block of code is an
>   expression and must have a result. 'let' can not be the final code
>   element in a block. Consider giving this block an explicit result.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You have to do something with `result`, as the message says, each block of code is an expression. Take a look at some of the examples in the [documentation:]( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/exception-handling/the-try-with-expression). Btw, you should only return `unit`, that's what the () is, for side effects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that `let` by itself is not an expression:

In F# everything is an expression of a certain type. But `let` alone is not an expression, is a binding and it has to be continued with some expression that, presumably, uses the value bound to the id `result`.

Since you are merely testing the try/catch functionality. I assume you are not really interested in producing any values, that is why I added the expression: `()` after the `let`.

```
try
    let result = 100/0
    ()
with
    ex -> printfn "%s" ex.Message
```

The `try/with` expression requires that both sides return the same type of value, just like `if/then/else` does. Since in the `with` side `printfn` returns `unit`, I made the `try` side also return a `unit` value which is `()`. Think of it as the equivalent to `void` in C#.

Comment: The same problem remains

Comment: Can you explain me `()` ?

Comment: Without `()`, what would it be like in C #?

Comment: `void MyFunction()` in F# translates to: `let MyFunction() = ()` which is of type: `unit -> unit`. The first unit is the parameter `()` the second one is the returned value which is also `()`.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend different approach. This won't leave the `result` variable undefined.

```
let result =
    try
        Some(100/0)
    with
        | :? Exception as ex -> printfn "%s" ex.Message; None
```